# google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it

Tags: android

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

    File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
       Searched Location: 
      C:\Users\Latif\AndroidStudioProjects\tutorialUp\app\src\nullnull\debug\google-services.json
      C:\Users\Latif\AndroidStudioProjects\tutorialUp\app\src\debug\nullnull\google-services.json
      C:\Users\Latif\AndroidStudioProjects\tutorialUp\app\src\nullnull\google-services.json
      C:\Users\Latif\AndroidStudioProjects\tutorialUp\app\src\debug\google-services.json
      C:\Users\Latif\AndroidStudioProjects\tutorialUp\app\src\nullnullDebug\google-services.json
      C:\Users\Latif\AndroidStudioProjects\tutorialUp\app\google-services.json
```

Here is the prove that I have added the json file:

[image: here is the pic]

Comment: i really want to know

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Prove to us that you have a `google-services.json` file in any of the locations mentioned above

Comment: You need the configuration file to use certain google services:
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=en

Comment: // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

Comment: // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {

    repositories {


        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: i have done the configuration from the firebase.com and also added the google-services.json file in the app but still

Comment: but still having the error

Comment: cricket_007 you can see the pic

Comment: Delete the "(6)" in the name of the file, rename it "google-services.json"

Comment: i did the same steps bro but still that error is there Belbahar Raouf

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

It has to be named 'google-services.json': remove the ' (6)' from the file name.

Also, if you're using multiple build types/flavours, you might wanne put it in app/src, too.

Also, add:

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

to build.gradle.